# $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $M$ iff $f$ is absolutely continuous and $|f'| < M$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

I have problems proving one of the directions.
First, we can use the following arguments:

If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, then it has bounded variation, and therefore it is differentiable almost everywhere on some interval $[a,b]$. Therefore, there exists a function $f'(x) : f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b f'(t) dt$

Now, since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $M$

$$\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|} \leq M$$

and taking limits $y \to x$ we get

$$|f'(x)| \leq M$$

For the converse, I tried to work this last argument backwards but I run into problems when getting rid of the limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute continuity implies Lipschitz iff $\sup(f'(x))&lt;\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098505/absolute-continuity-implies-lipschitz-iff-supfx-infty)

Comment: Thank you, but I will use the answer given since it is simpler and does not use yet another lemma.

Answer (score 3):

Going the other way, if it is absolutely continuous and $|f'| \leq M$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| = \left | \int_x^y f'(z) dz \right | \leq M|x-y|$ which gives Lipschitz.